# Elasticsearch: indeterministic data corruption on replicas

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to refer to this aprt of documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_partial_updates_to_a_document.html
Namely the last blue box and its last sentence.

> When a primary shard forwards changes to its replica shards, it
>   doesn’t forward the update request. Instead it forwards the new
>   version of the full document. Remember that these changes are
>   forwarded to the replica shards asynchronously, and there is no
>   guarantee that they will arrive in the same order that they were sent.
>   **If Elasticsearch forwarded just the change, it is possible that
>   changes would be applied in the wrong order, resulting in a corrupt
>   document.**

So what does it mean? 
It says that sometimes if the random asynchronous order is unfortunate then the replica will contain a corrupt document (?) It does not seem reliable for an industry solution.

**If this the above is true then how one can eliminate this problem of indeterministic data corruption on replicas?**

Comment: It's saying that, **if** it did do that, then there could be problems, but it does **not** do that, so there are not problems.

Comment: I don't understand. It says `Instead it forwards the new version of the full document` so the primary forward the change in form of the full document. How can primary not do that? In that case the replica would not have the document.

Comment: You are taking the sentence out of the context. Read carefully: _it doesn’t forward the update request. Instead it forwards the new version of the full document_ and then _If Elasticsearch forwarded just the change, it is possible that changes would be applied in the wrong order, resulting in a corrupt document._ So ES is not forwarding the change but the complete updated document and thus there is no wrong order of updates.

Comment: I understood that there might be inconsistencies across all replicas not a single replica. Because, what if replica document got changed before the entire document from primary shard would arrive?